# Single Sign On for only part of users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

For a few days have I been struggling with research on Single Sign On mechanism in ASP.NET, however I still cannot find an answer to a problem which I need to solve. I've read several articles about the mechanism (including https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/introducing-single-sign-on-to-an-existing-asp.net-mvc-application/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic), but think that I either cannot fully understand how it works or I am looking for a wrong thing.

If I understood well, Single Sign On is a mechanism which allows to authenticate a user across all connected web applications with single credentials. However, what I need to do is to allow only some users from application A to access some features in application B by clicking a hyperlink (because only some users will have account in both applications). Both applications should have an independent login mechanism (because some users should have access to only one of the applications), but when the user loggs in the application A and have an account in application B, he should be signed in both apps (not necessarily the other way round).

And here comes the question: is single-sign-on with centralised authentication really what I need here? And if yes, how could I use it only for some of users? I'd be very grateful if someone could explain it to me or provide a source, where I can find more information about it.

Comment: Well I think you are confusing authentication with _authorisation_.  The former determines _who someone is_ whilst the latter is _what can they do_.   You can use SSO across the board but _deny_ certain users from performing certain things in certain sites or deny them entirely.  It doesn't mean you should have a mix of SSO and non-SSO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I know the difference but I still had a problem with figuring out the solution. But thanks to what you wrote, I thought of one thing. If I understand correctly, either if the user has an account in both apps or not, I can treat him as authenticated (which means storing an auth cookie) and then inside the application I can check if he's got enough permissions and if not e.g. sign him off and again redirect to the login screen, right?

Comment: No probs. Yes, that sounds pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, now I finally understand it :-) I've got only one more question. I was wondering if there is a simpler method which would not need to use the centralized identity server, e.g. one presented on the sequence diagram under 'A very basic Cross Domain SSO implementation model' here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic . What would you say about that solution according to what I wrote in the question?

Comment: Well I think the net effect is OK i.e. _the user need only login once_; though I'm not sure about the execution.  The problem with it is that a single site now depends on the other two being accessible during the redirects (as opposed to just one SSO provider site). If one is down it breaks. Also, now all 3 sites have to worry about providing a "login" page just in case the user visits that site first (the article assumes its always `domain1`).  It's a bit of an **ad-hoc** SSO in exactly the same way as you can do ad-hoc wi-fi with no central base station.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clean explanation. Your answers really helped me with understanding the problem.

Comment: Any-time good sir.  I have posted a summary below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is a summary of the conversation with the OP for fear of it being deleted.

---

OP:

> However, what I need to do is to allow only some users from application A to access some features in application B by clicking a hyperlink (because only some users will have account in both applications). Both applications should have an independent login mechanism (because some users should have access to only one of the applications), but when the user loggs in the application A and have an account in application B, he should be signed in both apps (not necessarily the other way round).

Are you thinking of authentication or authorisation? The former determines who someone is whilst the latter is what can they do. You can use SSO across the board but deny certain users from performing certain things in certain sites or deny them entirely. It doesn't mean you should have a mix of SSO and non-SSO

OP:

> Thanks for the answer. Actually, I know the difference but I still had a problem with figuring out the solution. But thanks to what you wrote, I thought of one thing. If I understand correctly, either if the user has an account in both apps or not, I can treat him as authenticated (which means storing an auth cookie) and then inside the application I can check if he's got enough permissions and if not e.g. sign him off and again redirect to the login screen, right?

No probs. Yes, that sounds pretty good.

OP:

> I've got only one more question. I was wondering if there is a simpler method which would not need to use the centralized identity server, e.g. one presented on the sequence diagram under 'A very basic Cross Domain SSO implementation model' [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic). What would you say about that solution according to what I wrote in the question?

Well I think the net effect is OK i.e. the user need only login once; though I'm not sure about the execution. The problem with it is that a single site now depends on the other two being accessible during the redirects (as opposed to just one SSO provider site). If one is down it breaks. Also, now all 3 sites have to worry about providing a "login" page just in case the user visits that site first (the article assumes its always domain1). It's a bit of an **ad-hoc SSO** in exactly the same way as you can do ad-hoc wi-fi with no central base station.

OP:

> And here comes the question: is single-sign-on with centralised authentication really what I need here? And if yes, how could I use it only for some of users?

I think the benefits of having a single mechanism outweigh maintaining separate login facilities in two or more applications. I don't see why you could not deny SSO for certain users.  The dependent site can easily determine if the user is logging on using a site-specific account or a SSO account.  In both cases account sign-up can be approved by an admin, rejecting certain applicants (particularly if it is an enterprise) or by merely using authorisation rules in the site.

Also you may be aware, just because a site can accept SSO, does not mean it is *exclusively SSO*.  Even groovy sites like *StackOverflow* accept logins from SO-local-accounts as well as from SSO providers like say *Google* and *Facebook*.

Comment: Once again thanks for your answer. It was really helpful and I understood the point of centralized SSO. Of course, you're right that having all authentication mechanisms in one place is a big advantage. The only reason why I was looking for a simpler solution is because it would take much less time and effort to implement, as we already have two apps with separate login screens and different authentication logic. We'll consider pros and cons of both solutions and choose the one that'll be best for our requirements. :-)

Comment: @PJDev Excellent.  Wishing you well.